# Dirichlet energy is non-increasing under the heat flow?

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis

M is a Riemannian manifold, $\Omega $ is a domain in M. Consider the Dirichlet form:$$\varepsilon \left( {u,v} \right) = \int_\Omega  {\left\langle {\nabla u,\nabla v} \right\rangle } $$ for $u,v \in W_0^{1,2}\left( \Omega  \right)$. ${T_t}$ is the induced semi-group. Then $\varepsilon \left( {{T_t}f,{T_t}f} \right)$ is non-increasing about t? Why? Is the property right for all Dirichlet form?

Answer (score 4):

Let us start with $f\in W^{2,2}\cap W^{1,2}_0$. Then $u(t)=T_tf$ is a classical solution of the heat equation. Let $E(t)=\varepsilon (u(t),u(t))$, then
$$\frac{d}{dt}E(t) = 2\int \langle \nabla u'(t),\nabla u(t)\rangle = -2\int u'(t)\Delta u(t) = -2\int |\Delta u(t)|^2 \leq 0,$$

hence $E(t) = \varepsilon(T_tf,T_tf)$ is non-increasing. Here integration is in the space variable and we use the theorem of Green.

If your initial value is not regular, then you have to use the smoothing property of the semigroup for $t>0$.